# Java - Condition is always True/False (Android Checkboxes)

Tags: java, android, if-statement, checkbox, conditional-statements

I have the following code to display a certain string according to which checkboxes are checked in my Android app:

```
public String createOrderSummary(){

    CheckBox whippedCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.whipped);
    boolean whippedCream = whippedCheckBox.isChecked();

    CheckBox chocoBox = findViewById(R.id.chocolate);
    boolean chocolate = chocoBox.isChecked();

    if (whippedCream && chocolate){
        return "both selected";
    }else if(whippedCream || chocolate){
        if (whippedCream){
            return "whippedcream";
        }else if (chocolate){
            return "chocolate";
        }
    }else{
        return "none checked";
    }
    return "";
}
```

I receive a warning at `line 14` saying `condition chocolate is always true`, why is that?

Also when I switch lines to be:

```
 if (whippedCream){
        return "whipped cream";
    }else if(whippedCream && chocolate){
        return "both selected";
    }else{
        return "none selected";
    }
```

I receive warning at `line 3` saying `condition always false`.

Comment: What is line 14 and what is line 3? In the second example, I presume line 3 is the third line from the top?

Comment: In the first example your nested statements are unnecessary and should be written as one clear string of if, else if, else if, else.  In the second example you need to check the most constrained condition first (the && condition), followed by the others.  This is similar to the common Fizz Buzz interview question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider part of your condition:

```
if (whippedCream || chocolate) { // either whippedCream is true or chocolate is true
    if (whippedCream) { // whippedCream is true
        return "whippedcream";
    } else if (chocolate) { // whippedCream is not true, so chocolate must be true
        return "chocolate";
    }
}
```

therefore this condition can be simplified:

```
if (whippedCream || chocolate) { // either whippedCream  is true or chocolate is true
    if (whippedCream) { // whippedCream is true
        return "whippedcream";
    } else { // chocolate must be true
        return "chocolate";
    }
}
```

Of course, the full condition can be further simplified by eliminating the inner condition:

```
if (whippedCream && chocolate) { // both true
    return "both selected";
} else if (whippedCream) { // only whippedCream is true
    return "whippedcream";
} else if (chocolate) { // only chocolate is true
    return "chocolate";
} else {
    return "none checked";
}
```

Your alternative condition:

```
if (whippedCream){
    return "whipped cream";
}else if(whippedCream && chocolate){
    return "both selected";
}else{
    return "none selected";
}
```

is simply wrong. If `whippedCream` is true, you'll never check if both `whippedCream` and `chocolate` are true, since the condition of `else if` is only evaluated if all the preceding conditions are false.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the code

```
}else if(whippedCream || chocolate){
    if (whippedCream){
        return "whippedcream";
    }else if (chocolate){
        return "chocolate";
    }
```

We'll only check `if (whippedCream)` if `whippedCream` or `chocolate` are `true`.  So, when we get to the `else if (chocolate)`, then we know `whippedCream` is `false`, or we would not be in the 2nd `else`.  We also know `chocolate` is true or we wouldn't be in this block.

Answer (score 0):

The message is because of how you have nested your ifs. You are entering `if (whippedCream || chocolate)` only if one of them is true. You then check each one individually when a simple else would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

It is logical phenomenon:

If this condition is true: `if(whippedCream || chocolate)` That means one of them either `whippedCream` or `chocolate` is `true` or both.

So inside it there is `if (whippedCream) else if(chocolate)` that means the second `if` in the `else if` is unnecessary. Because one of them is `true`, so if`(whippedCream)`is `false` then the `else` means chocolate is `true` and the condition `if(chocolate)` is unnecessary.